# Rails: How to get match method options from within view helpers and controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

There is a [match](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) method in Rails dedicated to set routes. It has a few options: `:controller`, `:action`, `:via`, etc. One of them is `:as` option.

> :as
>
> The name used to generate routing helpers.

For example, I have such a route setting:

```
match("user/hello' => "users#show",
      via: 'get',
      :as => :user_hello,
    )
```

This `:as` option lets me do this in my `html.erb` template:

```
<%= link_to("User Hello", user_hello_path()) %>
```

and I get this in my rendered page:

```
<a href="user/hello">User Hello</a>
```

But I'd like to change the default behavior of this helper. I want to add some prefix to the generated url, to have it like this one:

```
<a href="myprefix/user/hello">User Hello</a>
```

The question is, how to get that `:as` variable in my helper module file:

```
# File: C:\MyApp\app\helpers\users_helper.rb
module UsersHelper

    # I explicitly redefine the default helper
    # but can't get :as option here
    def user_hello_path
        "myprefix/" + :as.to_s  # <-- how to get the ":as" option here
    end
end
```

Also how to get all those `match` method options in controllers?

Comment: why are you not `namespace` on route ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use such thing as `namespace`
for example

```
namespace :yourprefix do
#your route here
end
```

and this will return you `"yourprefix/your_route"`

As of about your method - you can pass path into your method

```
def user_hello_path(user_path)
        "myprefix/" + user_path.to_s  # <-- how to get the ":as" option here
end
```

and somewhere in views

```
user_hello_path(user_hello(@user))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:as` option has nothing to do with the name of the route. You can perfectly have this:

```
get "myprefix/user/hello' => "users#show", as: 'user_hello'
```

But if you want to do something like grouping a certain number of routes under a custom prefix, you should do something with namespaces, which is explained in @Avdept's answer.